# Google api to add pop3 email account

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk, gmail-pop, google-admin-settings-api

is there and api to add an pop3 account to  a gmail account .. i did get a link to the api to enable and disable the pop setting api [Pop Settings link](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/#manage_pop_settings). but could not find the api to add an account from which i need to do a po

Comment: Hey, can you tell me how to enable pop? I tried the link you said, it doesn't work, and I also search the whole internet. It seems that Admin-SDK only work for business account, and it doesn't work on free gmail account. Right?

Comment: yes stony  admin  sdk only works with business accounts and not the free ones

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API currently that provides this capability.  As you stated, only changing the POP access settings to the account can be done with the current APIs.